# problem with cross-referencing after changing numerical list

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

While working with the following not so minimal example I noticed that the
cross referencing does not work properly, when changing the appearance of
enumerate labels. What do I have to change to make it work correctly?

I do not use `enumitem.sty` due to an incompatibility with the `beamer.cls`.

[Sorry, I am not allowed to upload anything, due to our security policy. The
result in the last line reads `see 2`, where it should be `see b`.]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\alph{enumi})}
\newenvironment{Enumerate}[1][0]{%
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
      \expandafter
    \begin{list}{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}{\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{{##1}}%
                 \setlength{\rightmargin}{\z@}%
                 \setlength{\itemindent}{\z@}%
                 \settowidth{\labelwidth}{99.}%
                 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
                 \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
                 \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
                 \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.25\labelwidth}%
                 \setlength{\labelsep}{0.25\labelwidth}}}
   {\end{list}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A

\begin{Enumerate}
 \item a
 \item b\label{B}
 \item c
\end{Enumerate}

See \ref{B}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your document ends `prematurely` ;-)

Comment: No longer any more ... ;-))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label is stored with `\theenumi`. This is the command you should redefine. `\labelenumi` is not enough-

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\labelenumi}{\theenumi)}
\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi}}
\newenvironment{Enumerate}[1][0]{%
    \advance\@enumdepth\@ne
    \edef\@enumctr{enum\romannumeral\the\@enumdepth}%
    \begin{list}{\csname label\@enumctr\endcsname}{\usecounter\@enumctr\def\makelabel##1{{##1}}%
                 \setlength{\rightmargin}{\z@}%
                 \setlength{\itemindent}{\z@}%
                 \settowidth{\labelwidth}{99.}%
                 \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}%
                 \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
                 \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
                 \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.25\labelwidth}%
                 \setlength{\labelsep}{0.25\labelwidth}}}
   {\end{list}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
A

\begin{Enumerate}
 \item a
 \item b\label{B}
 \item c
\end{Enumerate}

See \ref{B}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works like a charm! Many thanks, Ulrike, for the quick help.